# Having trouble with a JSP and the struts bean taglib when precompiling with jspc

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1, taglib

#### Prelude

I am using Struts 1.1 on a legacy project and I can't upgrade to a newer version:

#### I am getting the following error(s):

```
An error occurred at line: 6,331 in the generated java file
mustCodes cannot be resolved

An error occurred at line: 6,350 in the generated java file
mustDesc cannot be resolved
```

#### Here are the offending lines of code from the generated JSP source file:

Here is the JSP code that generates the code that causes the error:

```xml
<bean:define id="mustCodes" name="locateVehicleForm" property="mustHaveOptionCodes"/>
<bean:define id="mustDesc" name="locateVehicleForm" property="mustHaveOptionDescs"/>
```

Here is line 6,331

```
mustCodes = (java.lang.Object) _jspx_page_context.findAttribute("mustCodes");
```

Here is line 6,530

```
mustDesc = (java.lang.Object) _jspx_page_context.findAttribute("mustDesc");
```

---

This is not a duplicate of [Need help on pre-compiling legacy JSP pages with taglibs with attributes that aren't supported in Struts 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547411/need-help-on-pre-compiling-legacy-jsp-pages-with-taglibs-with-attributes-that-ar) 
That one is about attributes that don't exist in the .tld. This one is about generated code not declaring the types on the reference variable names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help on pre-compiling legacy JSP pages with taglibs with attributes that aren't supported in Struts 1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547411/need-help-on-pre-compiling-legacy-jsp-pages-with-taglibs-with-attributes-that-ar)

Comment: @RomanC - **Not a duplicate!** If you actually read the questions the other one is about attributes that don't exist in the `.tld`. This one is about generated code not declaring the types on the reference variable names.

Comment: You may have thousands errors precompiling JSPs with taglibs of the framework released a decade ago and already dead. So, for each one will you create a new question?